# error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'. in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting below compile error in angular
error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.

Code in .ts file:

```html
searchTerm!: string;
page = 1;
pageSize = 4;
collectionSize!: number;
currentRate = 8;
countries: Country[]=[];
```

Code in component.html:

```html
<tr
  *ngFor="
    let country of countries
      | listFilter: searchTerm
      | slice: (page - 1) * pageSize:page * pageSize
  "
>
  <td style="width: 20px">
    {{ country.name }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Show more code. How you init 'countries'? If it is compile error, then you, mayby, dont import 'Country' type.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.